# Data insertion issue using cakephp 3.2 to oracle 11g tables

Tags: oracle, cakephp

I am just trying to build a simple crud application using cakephp and oracle. But when i am trying to add a new data from my add.ctp its return with this error. can anyone help. Errors are below.

```
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("HR"."EMP"."EMP_ID")
CakeDC\OracleDriver\Database\OCI8\OCI8Exception
```

BTW here 'EMP_ID' is primary key of 'EMP' table and i have also created sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to create all tables strctures using cakephp migrations.
The reason of that - datasource when create table dditionally create not only sequence, but also a triger, to fill id field. Also driver written in way to follow cakephp table field naming conventions. So you can just take EMP schema and get everything work.

Options are: create all tables using migrations from cakephp side, or write trigger that will fill id fields manual on oracle side.